# Microsoft Access macro to handle copy-paste insertion

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010, copy-paste

Seems like I've been hitting quite a number of pitfalls after starting out on Microsoft Access. Anyway, the latest one is this: my macro will auto-populate a field in my (datasheet) form whenever the record is dirty, which means that for this field everything is totally behind-the-scenes. Sounds good!

I faced a problem when trying to copy-paste over several columns from Excel though. Access didn't seem to recognise that I was "dirty-ing" more than one row, and consequently help me to auto-populate the fields of all these rows. Instead, it threw me the error message **You must enter a value in the "xx.xx" field.** followed by a disappointing **Do you want to suppress further error messages telling you why records can't be pasted?**. It seems `Form_Dirty()` isn't sufficient for my purposes...

Is there any solution or workaround for this? Let me know your comments and ideas, I'll be more than glad to listen :)

Comment: Can't you use default values on the field definition?

Comment: Can't do that, because I'm intending to use different forms to automatically populate the field with different values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dirty` event only fires once for the form:

> The Dirty event occurs when the contents of a form or the text portion
>   of a combo box changes. It also occurs when you move from one page to
>   another page in a tab control.

You can programmatically set the `DefaultValue` for each form. It needs to be set specifically to a string, though, so requires additional quotes:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtFirstName.DefaultValue = """Dave"""
End Sub
```